# Powershell Copy item from Array to Array

Tags: powershell, dayofweek, get-childitem, copy-item

I would like to copy folders that have a `DateTime` format to a folder with the name of Weekday. The Folder D:\TEST\2015-06-23T2300+0000 should be copied to D:\TEST\Thursday.

```
Get-ChildItem $Path | Select FullName
D:\TEST\2015-06-23T2300+0000                                                                            
D:\TEST\2016-01-07T2300+0000                          

Get-ChildItem $Path | ForEach {$_.LastWriteTime.DayOfWeek}
Thursday
Friday
```

Here is the code I have a the moment but it is not working. I am missing something.

```
$Path = "D:\TEST"
$source = Get-ChildItem $Path | Select FullName
$dest = Get-ChildItem $Path | ForEach {$_.LastWriteTime.DayOfWeek}
  foreach ($source in $sources)
    {
    Copy-Item -Path $source -Destination "D:\TEST2\$dest" -Recurse
    }
```

Any help welcome.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What exactly happens? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: In your example, `$dest` becomes a string array containing *all* the possible weekdays for all your files - `Copy-Item -Destination` can't "guess" which one belongs to each file

Comment: Nothing happens just takes the script. No output and no files copied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're populating `$dest` with all possible Weekday values.

Retrieve the weekday on a per-item basis, as you go through them and copy:

```
$Sources = Get-ChildItem $Path
foreach($Source in $Sources)
{
    $Weekday = $Source.LastWriteTime.DayOfWeek
    $Destination = "D:\Test\$Weekday"

    Copy-Item $Source.FullName -Destination $Destination -Recurse    
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: Had to change `Copy-Item $Source.FullName -Destination $Destination\$Source -Recurse` to maintain the folder structure inside the Weekday folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,
It is working, I have tested:

```
$Dir = "c:\files"
$Items = Get-ChildItem -Path $Dir
foreach ($Item in $Items)
{
    if (!($Item -is [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]))
    {
        Copy-Item -Path $Item.FullName -Destination .\Desktop\$($Item.LastAccessTime.DayOfWeek)
    }
}
```

- This directory c:\files should have a subdirectory foreach day of the week.